# Time taken by field inside a Conductor to become zero

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Say we have a thin hollow conducting sphere in empty space. Then an external uniform electric field is suddenly induced.

How can we calculate the time it will take the charge carriers to redistribute themselves until the net internal electric field becomes zero?

Comment: This actually depends upon the resistivity of the materials involved and the geometries and everything. AlphaPhoenix on YouTube has a wonderful video where he used a lot of oscilloscopes to figure out what the voltage propagation of a suddenly connected source into split lanes would be doing, where one lane is a dead end and the other lane is connected to a resistor and back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since eventually it will reach an equilibrium where the field inside is zero, we can just look at the deviation from this equilibrium: how fast will this become zero? This means you split off the solution for the steady state and use linearity.

That leaves you with a situation without an external field (which is already in the steady state) and you have some charge distribution on the sphere which has to go to zero. Describe it using spherical harmonics, $Y_{lm}$'s, and you will see that the lowest possible mode, with $l=1$, is the slowest. That is essentially the mode with positive charge on the upper half and negative charge on the bottom half of the sphere. The finer ripples will decay faster.

I leave the mathematics to you, but for the slowest mode a first estimate will of course be found by just using the RC description: the capacitance between top and bottom of the sphere and the resitansce between top and bottom. Those  C and R must be in the order of $\varepsilon_0 r$ and $\rho$ respectively, where $r$ is the sphere's radius and $\rho$ the resistance per square of its surface. So the time constant will be in the order of $\rho 
 \ \varepsilon_0 r$.

Comment: I realise the question is a little bit completely beyond my syllabus, gotta do some reading on this now im intrigued.

Any resources you could recommend? i couldn't find much on this topic

Comment: The simple picture with the top-bottom capacitance is of course trivial, so you mean the $Y_{lm}$ stuff, I assume. I learned that from Jackson, "Classical Electrodynamics", but also from QM texts (but they deal with other kinds of waves and are a bit out of scope here).

Comment: yep, thanks for that